# I'm trying to add a tooltip to an a tag in my code but it throws an error :Cannot create property 'position' on string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function apply_glossary(arr) {

  var res_string = document.querySelector(".show-content").innerHTML;

  arr.forEach(function(e) {

    var tooltip_string = "<a style= 'border-bottom: 2px dotted black; color:inherit; text-decoration:none;' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top'  href='#' id='tooltip-link' data-tooltip='" + e.content + "'>" + e.key + "</a>";

    res_string = replaceAll(res_string, e.key, tooltip_string);
  });

  document.querySelector(".show-content").innerHTML = res_string;
  console.log(res_string);


}

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Do you have any HTML to show us properly?

Comment: It is just a string with HTML. I dont know what function replaceAll do but you must append that HTML to proper place for ex. with jQuery $(parent).append(res_str)

Answer (score 0):

You can't adjust innerHTML by naming it a variable, that ***gets*** it. Change this line:

```
    var res_string = document.querySelector(".show-content").innerHTML;
```

To this:

```
    var res_string = document.querySelector(".show-content");
```

And this line:

```
res_string = replaceAll(res_string, e.key, tooltip_string);
```

With this:

```
res_string.innerHTML = replaceAll(res_string, e.key, tooltip_string);
```